# centrar titulo con css

Tags: css, reactjs

estoy creando una e-commerce y me trabe al intentar que quede el nombre de la pagina en el centro. estoy trabajando con el framework react.js, tengo un componente que se llama NavBar y dentro tengo un navbar.js donde tengo el código html escrito con jsx y un navbar.css. quiero centrar el "Vanilla. Deco&hogar" (a y h6) inserto el código a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a centrarlo

```
  <header>
       <nav className='navbar navbar-expand'>
          <div className='container-fluid'>
             <a className='title' href=" ">Vanilla</a>
             <h6 className='title' id='title-small'>Deco&Hogar</h6>
             <button className='navbar-toggler' type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=" navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
             </button>
             <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
              <ul className='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <a className='nav-link active' aria-current="page" href=" ">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item'>
                  <a className='nav-link' href=" ">Link</a>
                </li>
                <li className='nav-item dropdown'>
                  <a className='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href=" " role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                  </a>
                   <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
                    <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Action</a></li>
                    <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Another action</a></li>
                    <li><hr className='dropdown-divider'/></li>
                    <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Something else here</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
                 <li className='nav-item'>
                  <a className='nav-link disabled'>Disabled</a>
                </li> 
               </ul>
               <form className='d-flex' role="search">
                  <input className='form-control me-2' type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search"/>
                  <button className='btn btn-outline-success' type="submit">Search</button>
               </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>



nav{
background-color: #eee3d0;

}

 .title{
font-family: 'Italiana', serif;
color: #937653;
font-size: 50px;
text-decoration: none;
}

 #title-small{
font-size: larger;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 50px;
margin-left: 30px;
}
```

Comment: una de las formas para centrar un elemento con css es aplicar un `margin: 0 auto;` a tu elemento (el que quieres centrar). Esto centrara el elemento dentro de su contenedor padre, es decir que si quieres el elemento realmente en el centro el contenedor padre debe ocupar el 100 % de ancho de la pagina

Comment: @David081 lo intente pero no sucede ningún cambio

Comment: al parecer estas usando bootstrap, puedes intentar agregando esto a tu elemento que quieres centrar `className="mx-auto"`

Comment: @David081 malas noticias, tampoco hay ningún cambio, quizá hay alguna propiedad que lo impida, no lo se...

Comment: agrega  la clase de bootstrap `d-flex justify-content-center` o `text-center`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, esto es lo que he descubierto...

Hasta ahora tienes un `title-small` modificando las propiedades de lo que quieres cambiar, lo que vuelve todo MAS complicado al tener `position: absolute` y `margins`.

Acá te dejo un mini arreglo, el cual solo incluye lo que quieres dentro de un `center`, para centrar esos objetos. Y he quitado esas propiedades en conflicto.

Espero esto te ayude a solucionar tu error.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #eee3d0;
}

.title {
  font-family: 'Italiana', serif;
  color: #937653;
  font-size: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#title-small { /* ESTE ES EL QUE CAMBIA */
  font-size: larger;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.6/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-oBqDVmMz9ATKxIep9tiCxS/Z9fNfEXiDAYTujMAeBAsjFuCZSmKbSSUnQlmh/jp3" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-mQ93GR66B00ZXjt0YO5KlohRA5SY2XofN4zfuZxLkoj1gXtW8ANNCe9d5Y3eG5eD" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<header>
  <nav className='navbar navbar-expand'>
    <div className='container-fluid'>
      <center>
        <a className='title' href=" ">Vanilla</a>
        <h6 className='title' id='title-small'>Deco&Hogar</h6>
      </center>
      <button className='navbar-toggler' type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target=" navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span className='navbar-toggler-icon'></span>
      </button>
      <div className='collapse navbar-collapse' id='navbarSupportedContent'>
        <ul className='navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0'>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link active' aria-current="page" href=" ">Home</a>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link' href=" ">Link</a>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item dropdown'>
            <a className='nav-link dropdown-toggle' href=" " role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
            </a>
            <ul className='dropdown-menu'>
              <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Action</a></li>
              <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Another action</a></li>
              <li>
                <hr className='dropdown-divider' />
              </li>
              <li><a className='dropdown-item' href=" ">Something else here</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li className='nav-item'>
            <a className='nav-link disabled'>Disabled</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <form className='d-flex' role="search">
          <input className='form-control me-2' type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search" />
          <button className='btn btn-outline-success' type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```